# Extract email addresses of Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get e-mail addresses from Gmail messages received](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/get-e-mail-addresses-from-gmail-messages-received)

I have a Google Apps Gmail account and I would like to extract all email addresses in the `from` and `to` (and `cc`, `bcc` and `reply-to` if possible) headers of every message.

How can I do this?

I've found a site (https://gmailextract.com/) that promises to do exactly what I need, but I don't think I can trust it with my password.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean extract the addresses from each incoming email and save them somewhere, or extract all the addresses you've ever sent or received anything from ever?

Comment: The latter, but if it can't be done, the former will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it the old fashion offline way:

1) Download all mails with [Gmail Backup](http://www.gmail-backup.com/) or an IMAP client if you only want headers

2) Use a regexp tool on the downloaded files or headers to find the email adresses and save the result into a text file

3) Optionally import the file into Contacts in Gmail