# Export all sender's email addresses for a specific label in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, export, contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get e-mail addresses from Gmail messages received](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/get-e-mail-addresses-from-gmail-messages-received)

I have a site with a contact form that sends messages straight to my inbox, and I've set up a filter to give all those emails a label.

I'd like to export the email addresses of all the people who wrote to me through that contact form. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://groups.google.com/group/gmail-labs-help-filter-import-export/browse_thread/thread/1dfdeec4e85f11cd) from a Google Group suggests using an IMAP client to do the email address exporting.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [GmailExtractor.com](http://www.gmailextractor.com) and see if that helps. You can extract all unique email addresses from a Gmail mailbox label. Note that it is not 100% free.

Comment: this is not the place to advertise.