# How can I grab all email addresses associated with a "label" in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get e-mail addresses from Gmail messages received](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/get-e-mail-addresses-from-gmail-messages-received)

In Gmail, you can tag one or more emails with a Label:

[image]

I know I can select the label to see the emails in question, but what I want is to get everyone's *email address* associated with these labels for export. In the above image, I'd want the email addresses of Lifestreams Blog, Ozh, and WordPress since they're tagged 'planetozh'.

EDIT:

Let's assume I can download all the emails into Mozilla Thunderbird and view the emails in an ordered list with the label set correctly (using IMAP). How could I export the list of email addresses (duplicates are not a problem) this way?

Comment: BTW, where did you get this ancient gmail interface?

Comment: Dunno. Just googled for "gmail labels" or something. Didn't want to take a picture of my own email client and go through blacking out and possible confusion.

Comment: **Very** similar to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17492/export-all-senders-email-addresses-for-a-specific-label-in-gmail which was closed as a duplicate of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/get-e-mail-addresses-from-gmail-messages-received

Comment: Those help, sort of - they don't talk about labels, though. I have hundreds of thousands of emails in my account, which isn't going to be all that useful. While I have some experience with shell scripting and database management, I was hoping the answer wouldn't be that... coarse.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this being closed as an exact duplicate. I wanted to offer a bounty on this, because those posts do NOT answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

`label:planetozh` in the search bar should return any emails with that tag. Using an IMAP account, you can pull in those labels and make a contact list. Export the contact list to excel or csv.

Comment: OP said, "I know I can select the label to see the emails in question"

Comment: Would downvote if I could, alas I'm only 106 rep on SuperUser. I need email addresses, not emails.

Comment: Kobaltz edited his answer. Where would I go in Thunderbird to create said contact list? I have it imported via IMAP and have the messages open in the label.

Comment: I don't know if Thunderbird will work. Does it have an address book or contacts module? Last time I looked at it was a dealbreaker since I did not want to use the Lightning Calendar thingy.

Comment: It has both. But I have Outlook open with them imported and the label up. I select them all, right-click, and nothing promising comes up. Ideas?