# How to get the list of email addresses in a Gmail labelled folder?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get e-mail addresses from Gmail messages received](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/get-e-mail-addresses-from-gmail-messages-received)

I've got a bunch of emails into a labelled folder in Gmail and I would like to extract the list of email addresses from it. How can I do that?