# Extract/export email addresses from a Gmail search

Tags: gmail, export

I want to export all the email addresses the come up with a specific search query in Gmail. Anybody know some tricks or apps?

Comment: Closely related: [Get e-mail addresses from Gmail messages received](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/9813)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new label and assign them all to that label. Then when you extract you can choose that label and it will only extract those to your export file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but you can not export a message label, only contact labels. That mains I have to make of every mailadres a contact? :(

Comment: You didn't say export messages. You said email addresses, to me that equals contacts. So what are your trying to export? Contacts or messages? Sounds like you are wanting email addresses from only certain messages. I would think the answer is the same then. Run a search for messages (filter) and then take all the contacts for those messages and assign them to a new label. What am I missing here?

Comment: I am trying to export the email addresses of the persons who come up in the list when I search for: Newsletter Yes.
This people are not in my contacts list. And if I make a label only the messages will be labeled, not the contacts.

With export you only can export contact-labels for so far I see.

Comment: Other than the obvious manual way (searching then opening each result and adding the contact to a group). Google does not support searching between contacts AND messages.

Comment: It would probably be faster to assign all these emails to a new label, download all emails with an email program capable of IMAP and then search in these files for email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2017**

LennyLabs have changed GeeExtract to [deep-email-extractor.com](https://deep-email-extractor.com)

**Original Answer**

An app we use every now and then is GeeExtract form LennyLabs Ltd

You can extract all your email addresses from your whole Gmail account OR a single Label. I was reminded of it as they recently emailed boasting email Body scanning too, if its true that's quite powerful.

By the way its a paid app, it aint much and I have nothing to do with them (for the record)

Answer (score 1):

https://helgeklein.com/blog/2015/02/extracting-all-email-addresses-from-a-gmail-label/

Full instuctions on the site:  Script is based in a google spreadsheet.  Type the label in B1 (it will tell you...) Run script.  Do something else.  Took about 10 mintues to find 2000 addresses in 15 GB of gmail.