# Get email addresses from Gmail message body

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, google-contacts, export

I've found this lovely script from another thread:
[Get e-mail addresses from Gmail messages received](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/get-e-mail-addresses-from-gmail-messages-received#answer-60325).

It works great! However, what I'm trying to do is pull the contact info from the message body, as a lot of our older emails came from the same `info@ourdomain.com` address.

All of these emails are incoming (via WordPress contact form 7) and they all have the same message body. The first line in the message is always:

```
From: Name <name@example.com>
```

What would I need to do to capture the name and email into a spreadsheet?

Ideally, the A column would capture the Name and B column would capture the email address.

Comment: May also try with Email Extractor that may help you.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to write some sort of regex to extract that string from the message.

```
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();

for (var t in threads) {

  var messages = threads[t].getMessages[];
  var text = messages[0].getPlainBody();

  var matches = /From:(.*?)<(.*?)>/gi.exec(text);
  if (matches) 
      Logger.log(matches[1] + " :: " + matches[2]);

}
```