# Get all email addresses associated to a specific Gmail label

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, gmail-labels

How to get the list of all emails addresses associated to a Gmail label?

i.e. in a similar way than [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/get-e-mail-addresses-from-gmail-messages-received) question, but limited to a **specific label**?

---

<sup>Note: I post here with *Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style*, because I don't have enough rep to post an answer in the aforementioned question.</sup>

Comment: Yes @pnuts, I'm sure - association bonus doesn't count. Anyway this question here is a little different, in the sense it's specific to a label.

Comment: I tried @pnuts, but didn't work there: the site didn't let me post there.

Comment: Yes @pnuts. But not a big deal, happy to have found a solution for this email-addresses-extraction from a label :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new script on http://script.google.com,
2. Past the code below,
3. Open the menu *Publish > Deploy web app...*, and copy/paste the script URL<sup>(*)</sup>,
4. Run the script with the URL (accept the permission questions about Gmail):

   ```
   https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../dev?label=nameofthelabel
   ```

   It will directly [display the addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46106339/1422096) in the browser, without needing a spreadsheet or anything else.

Code:

```
function doGet(e) {
    var max = 100;
    var offset = 0;
    var searchThreads = [];
    var addresses = [];

    while (true) {
      var threads = GmailApp.search("label:" + e.parameter.label, offset, max);
      searchThreads = searchThreads.concat(threads);
      if (threads.length < max) { break; }
      offset += max;
    }  

    for (var i = 0; i < searchThreads.length; i++) {
      var messages = searchThreads[i].getMessages();
      for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
        addresses.push(messages[j].getFrom());
      }
    }

    function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { return self.indexOf(value) === index; }
    var addr = addresses.filter(onlyUnique).join('\n');

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(addr).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

---

(*) Choose the "latest code" link, ending with `/dev` , it avoids to redeploy each time you do a tiny modification in code, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141589/google-apps-script-web-app-automatically-linked-to-latest-code).