# What's Other Contacts?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

In Gmail under other contacts there are people that I never contacted and have no clue who they are. Why are they there? How do they get on there?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways people can be added to your "Other" contacts:

1. You used Google+ and they were in one or more of your Circles
2. You have emailed them in the past and the setting "Create contacts for auto-complete" is turned on (See: [Stop Gmail from automatically creating contacts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1987/354)). Used to be that you couldn't control that setting, so if you've been using Gmail since before April 2011 that might be where they're from.